Measuring a high VCM signal with an isolated ADC - Differential or single ended?
I'm trying to measure a signal with high common mode voltage using a SPI isolator w/ integrated DCDC and an AD7732/7734 (One has 4 single ended inputs, one has two differential inputs). If AGND is floating, would having the signal come in on the differential inputs lead to potentially high VCM between AGND and AIN? If so, would it be better to measure using single ended inputs, tying one side of the signal to be measured to AGND?

The directly connected isolated AGND will be a capacitive load for the signal. Would this be an issue for the signal source?

@Jens I don't think so. The source will either be a bipolar analog signal voltage or a resistor in a 4-20mA current loop.

The AD7732 is a high resolution converter with a relative low input impedance (around 100 kohm). Your source signal impedance must be very low or you need a buffer amplifier in between. I tend to the single ended version.
